# Passing vector space structure via surjective map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space, and let $W$ be a set. Let further $+ : W \times W \to W , \cdot : K \times W \to W$ be maps, and let 
$ A : V \to W$ be a surjective map, such that
$$ \forall x ,y \in V \forall \lambda \in K : A(\lambda x + y) = \lambda A(x) + A(y). $$

I am asked to show that this induces a $K$-vector space structure on $W$.

However, I can't seem to prove either of the following equivalent statements $$ \begin{align*} (1) &\text{  } A(0) \text{ is right-neutral}, \\ (2)&\text{  } 1\cdot w = w \text{ for any }w \in W. \end{align*} $$

I am now very uncertain, whether the statement actually holds (without assuming (1) or (2)) - but I can't find a counter example either. Thus my question: is the statement true?

Comment: You're using some terminology with which I'm not familiar. To be clear, let me know if this is what you're asking: you wish to show that $+$ and $\cdot$ form the addition and scalar multiplication on $W$ (using this surjective map $A$), but you're struggling to prove that $w + A(0) = w$ for all $w \in W$ (and $1 \cdot w = w$ for any $w \in W$)?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Consider the three conditions (a) $A(\lambda x + y) = \lambda A(x) + A(y)$, (b) $A(x + y) = A(x) + A(y)$ and (c)  $A(\lambda x) = \lambda A(x)$. Then (b) + (c) imply (a), (1) and (2). Moreover, both (a) + (1) and (a) + (2) imply (b) and (c). But it seems to me that (a) is too weak to derive (1) or (2). I would therefore try to find a counterexample.

Comment: Precisely my line of thought, but I failed at finding a counterexample. (Also, sorry for not including this in the post...)

Answer (score -1):

For $1)$ Let $w = A(v)$, which we can do since $A$ is surjective. $w + A(0) = A(v) + A(0) = A(v+0) = A(v) = w$, so $A(0)$ is right-neutral

For $2)$ let $w = A(v)$, which we can do since A is surjective. Then $1\cdot w = 1\cdot A(v) = A(1\cdot v) = A(v) = w$, as needed.

Edit: Okay. Currently, I think it's possible that we don't necessarily get a vector space structure out of the above definition without at least a few extra structural demands on + and $\cdot$ on W. However, the proper rebuke would come in the form of a counterexample structure... which is too much to ask.

Comment: In (1) you have used (2), since you need to use $1 \cdot A(v) = A(v)$ to obtain $A(v) +A(0) = 1 \cdot A(v) +A(0) = A(1v +0)=A(v)$.